# Parsing Logic, C# - Exception System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, parsing, logic

I have a huge data file looking somewhat like this:

```
TRANSACTION NUMBER                         AMOUNT      CNCY SVC DISPOSITION DATE/TIME          %     PT    FT    USER        LOC 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
CA150723052447000I0002                      38,078.100 CAD  BOK AUTO HOLD   23 JUL 15 17:19:53 100.0 80.0  101.0 SYSTEM      IBD 

CA150723052447000I0002  - User Actions and Comments:

User     Location Disposition          Date/Time             Comments                                                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
IBDGWYNETH IBD      MANUAL INVQ          23 JUL 15 17:20:29  inv  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 


CA150724020822000I0002                      36,106.000 CAD  BOK AUTO HOLD   24 JUL 15 08:19:32 100.0 80.0  101.0 SYSTEM      IBD 

CA150724020822000I0002  - User Actions and Comments:

User     Location Disposition          Date/Time             Comments                                                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
IBDADAM  IBD      MANUAL INVQ          24 JUL 15 08:25:17  investigate
```

What I am trying to do is use the values SYSTEM and 101.0 as they are consistent for each `Transaction Number`. And when I find this I am using the `substring` function to separate each of the details. Right now I am just worried about the line starting from CA1507.... 38,078.....SYSTEM.....IBD and separate all the attributes.

So far the code I have is below. Its throwing an exception `ArgumentOutOfRange`. Drilling down into it, the variable line has the value = "" causing this exception. Any ideas on how to work around this?

Thanks.

```
Boolean IsTxnSection = false;

StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\.....);

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //Transaction details
    if (IsTxnSection)
    {
        TransactionNo = line.Substring(0, 22).Trim();
        Console.WriteLine("TrnNo", TransactionNo);
    }

    if (line.Contains("101.0") && line.Contains("SYSTEM") && line.StartsWith("CA150"))
    {
        IsTxnSection = true;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(100);
    counter++;

    if (counter == 100)
        break;
}   // end of while

file.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been parsing test files for 40 years.  Here is how I've been doing it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        enum Section
        {
            NONE,
            TRANSACTION,
            USER
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Section section = Section.NONE;
            string TransactionNo = ""; 

            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0 && !line.StartsWith("---------------"))
                {
                    //Transaction details
                    switch (section)
                    {
                        case Section.NONE:
                            if(line.StartsWith("TRANSACTION NUMBER"))
                            {
                                section = Section.TRANSACTION;
                            }
                            break;
                        case Section.TRANSACTION:
                            if (!line.Contains("User Actions and Comments:"))
                            {
                                TransactionNo = line.Substring(0, 22).Trim();
                                Console.WriteLine("TrnNo : {0}", TransactionNo);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                section = Section.USER;
                            }
                            break;
                        case Section.USER:
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }//end of while
            file.Close();
       }
    }
}


​
```

Comment: Thanks Jdweng, the only reason I am not using line startswith Transaction number is because it appears just once in the whole file, hence the if conditions.

Comment: It is hard to determine exact logic with only the small portion of text posted.  I couldn't tell if file contained multiple transactions.  Using an enumeration and switch statement make code much easier to read and understand.  Not looking for Transaction Number makes it harder to ignore this line and can cause parsing error like you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
TransactionNo = line.Substring(0, 22).Trim();
```

If the line is shorter than 22 chars will raise that exception. Just skipe the line if it's shorter:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || line.Length < 22)
    continue;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But it gives an error when I use `if (IsTxnSection)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line) || line.Length < 22)
                        continue;
                    TransactionNo = line.Substring(0, 22).Trim();
                    Console.WriteLine("TrnNo", TransactionNo);
                }`
saying the string does not contain a definition for `IsNullorWhitespace`.

Comment: the string does not contain a definition for IsNullorWhitespace

Comment: Or you tiped it wrong (i see you put the "or" lowercase and it must be "Or") or you're using a framework lower than 3.5, if it's the framework, use IsNullOrEmpty instead

Comment: Actually, the S of space should have been in Uppercase. Thanks Gusman!

Comment: Yay, yes, sorry... that's the problem of writing code outside VS XD

Comment: Where should I place the if statement with isNullorEmpty ... continue?